# Change color of moreNavigationController Configure view

Tags: ios, tabbarcontroller

In my App I'm using an tabBarController with more than five viewControllers. For my app I changed the color of my all Navigation Bars including the navigation bar of the moreNavigationController. But if I'm editing the tab order a new view comes up and its navigationBar has another (standard) color.

[image: moreNavigationController.navigationBar]
[image]

Unfortunately I could not found where I have to change this color.

Could you give me a hint where I can do this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have same color for every nav bar in your app you can use UIAppeareance protocol (iOS 5+) and the settings will apply for every navigation bar in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is the UIAppeareance protocol method appearance:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Thanks to danypata for the comment!